# Keras.ImageDataGenerator result display [flow()]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to display images generated by the Imagedatagenerator.flow() but I am unable to do so.

I am using a single image and passing that to the .flow(img_path) to generate augmented images by until the total matches our requirement:

```
total = 0
for image in imageGen:
total += 1
if total == 10:
    break
```

the .flow()

```
imageGen = aug.flow(image_path, batch_size=1,
                      save_to_dir="/path/to/save_dir",
                      save_prefix="", save_format='png')
```

How do I receive the images as they were generating in the loop so that I can display it during the runtime?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use the image path you can use [flow_from_directory](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdirectory-method), and pass the image folder containing the single image. To obtain the images from the generator use `dir_It.next()` and access the first element, since the return of this function is:

> A DirectoryIterator yielding tuples of (x, y) where x is a numpy array containing a batch of images with shape (batch_size, *target_size, channels) and y is a numpy array of corresponding labels.

To diplay the image you can use `plt.imshow` from `matplotlib` passing the first (and only) image of the batch `plt.imshow(img[0])`.

Foder structure

```
├── data
│   └── smile
│       └── smile_8.jpg

# smile_8.jpg shape (256,256,3)
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=180,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
)

dir_It = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "data/",
    batch_size=1,
    save_to_dir="output/",
    save_prefix="",
    save_format='png',
)

for _ in range(5):
    img, label = dir_It.next()
    print(img.shape)   #  (1,256,256,3)
    plt.imshow(img[0])
    plt.show()
```

[image: smile_gen_hstack]

Comment: I did want to use only flow() method. Thanks for giving this explanation but I managed to get it working by putting a simple for loop and displaying the same image on my GUI.

Comment: I copy and pasted this code and changed dir_It to my directoryiterator.  I am getting the error message "'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'next'" I cannot find information on that.  Do I need to import something specific?